# html 'inception' cross browser issue

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have to show a preview of a html code (an entire html page which of course starts with html tag ...etc) from a textarea,using iframe. 
It works in webkit browsers but not in firefox.

Textarea:

```
<textarea id="document_token_body">the source code of a html page here</textarea>
```

The preview area:

```
<iframe id="result" width="680px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('result').contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.getElementById('document_token_body').value;
```

Comment: Whenever you're asking a technical question and you say something doesn't work, backspace over that and explain **exactly** what you expect it to do, and what you're seeing instead.

Comment: Side note (presumably not related to the problem you're having): The [`width` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-dim-width) of your `iframe` is invalid. It should simply be `width="680"` (or specified via CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLIFrameElement) instead of `contentWindow.document`.

Works for me in Firefox 20: http://jsfiddle.net/7vyDa/